# Show that $V=\text{ker}\,{f}\oplus\text{Im}\,{f}^{n-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know $V = \text{ker}\,{f}\oplus\text{Im}\,{f}$
when $f^2=f$.
Now I want to know that for $f^n =f$ what will be $V$? 
I think it should be  $V=\text{ker}\,{f}\oplus\text{Im}\,{f}^{n-1}$.
Am I correct? Could anyone help me to show that? Just a little hint plz :)

Comment: Yes, you ar e right. But indeed, $Im f^{n-1} = Im f$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Consider $f\cdot (f^{n-1}-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $\ker f\subset\ker f^2\subset\ldots$. Since the space is finite-dimensional, there has to be some $p$ such that $\ker f^p = \ker f^{p+1}$. By your condition $f^n = f$, we have $\ker f^n = \ker f$. Thus, $p=1$ and all kernels are equal. Similarly, all images $\operatorname{Im}f^k$ are equal to $\operatorname{Im}f$.

Let $x\in\ker f\cap\operatorname{Im}f$. Then $f(x) = 0$ and $x = f(y)$. Thus, $f^{2}(y) = 0$, which means $y\in\ker f^{2} = \ker f$, so $x = f(y) = 0$. This shows that $\ker f\cap\operatorname{Im}f = \{0\}$. By the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim\ker f + \dim\operatorname{Im}f = \dim V$. This finally proves that $V = \ker f\oplus\operatorname{Im}f$.

Comment: Thank you so much, now that is clear :)

Comment: Please check my answer if you are done.